# winforms measure available text in label

Tags: winforms, label

I have a label with an autosize set to false. I need to add text to it dynamically. The text will include of a specific word that I am searching for plus some text before and after to give context. 
I want to be able to know the width available I have in the label to know how many words I should display before and after my lookup word?

Comment: Use the ClientSize property.

Comment: how does that help me? My label is saying that it has the clientsize of 73. I counted 13 characters. I want to know how many characters my label can take.

Comment: I'm guessing you are overlooking the obvious one, it isn't exactly clear.  You'll need  TextRenderer.MeasureText() to know how much space a string will need.  If that doesn't fit inside ClientSize then it will be clipped.